# Gulp hangs after executing tasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm figuring out how gulp is working; it looks like the gulp tasks are being executed, but then it hangs.

Environment:

> node version `v14.17.0.`

gulp:

> CLI version: 2.3.0 Local version: 4.0.2

```
const babel = require("gulp-babel");

task("js",()=>{
    return src("src/*.js").pipe(babel()).pipe(dest("dist/js"));
})
task("moveHTML",()=>{
    return src("src/*.html").pipe(dest("dist"));
});
task("watch",()=>{
    watch("src/*.js",series("js"));
});
task("default",series('moveHTML','js','watch'));
```

There is no error here, but the execution is hanging. below is the node terminal message:

```
[10:30:29] Starting 'default'...

[10:30:29] Starting 'moveHTML'...

[10:30:29] Finished 'moveHTML' after 85 ms

[10:30:29] Starting 'js'...

[10:30:32] Finished 'js' after 3.22 s

[10:30:32] Starting 'watch'...
```

Comment: i think you are missing a semicolon after the first task. (not sure that would resolve the problem.

Comment: Also, What do you expect to happen after the `watch` task? It will only show changes if you modify files.

Comment: It works thank you @Dementic for your nice response

Answer (score 2):

The process persists because you are calling [`gulp.watch`](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/watch/) which returns an instance of `chokidar` and by default keeps the node process running.

If you want to stop the node process use the `persistent` option and set it to `false`.

```js
watch("src/*.js", { persistent: false }, series("js"));
```

**However, the gulp docs suggest not to do this.**